# App works on Android 5, but not 6

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to build an app to merge two Unity plugins, ARToolKit and CameraShot. The problem is that the manifest file for one of the plugins overwrites the other manifest file (in other words they both have to be at the same location). Fortunately, CameraShot specifies which activities are necessary and I was able to make a custom Android Manifest file.

The app works fine on Android 5, but crashes after I try to save an image taken with CameraShot on Android 6. I assumed this occurred due to the changes in permission granting, but I have checked the installed app's permissions on both devices and they are identical.

On Android 5 the app requests permissions at install time and on Android 6 it requests permissions the first time I run the app.

Would it be possible to get some more ideas on why the app is working on one OS version and not the other one?

This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.company.app" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
<application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="org.artoolkit.ar.unity.UnityARPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="org.artoolkit.ar.base.camera.CameraPreferencesActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.astricstore.camerashots.CameraShotActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
    <activity android:name="eu.janmuller.android.simplecropimage.CropImage" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
```

I need to add: this is not an Android project, but a Unity one. So if you are going to refer to Android functions please say so and specify how to  get to them, as I have no experience with Android Studio.

Thank you for your understanding!

Error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.eContent.PandaART/org.artoolkit.ar.unity.UnityARPlayerActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1388)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.View cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
                                                                     at org.artoolkit.ar.unity.UnityARPlayerActivity.onResume(UnityARPlayerActivity.java:137)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6327)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1388) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please paste your error logs.

Comment: In Android 6.0 you ask user about permissions.

Comment: @lidkxx How can I get the error log from the Unity editor? I thought you can only do with Android Studio

Comment: @BrunoFerreira I assumed I have done so by adding the permissions to the manifest file. As I mentioned, the app requests for the permission the first time I run it and if I approve them they are displayed correctly when I look into the app details. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that. Aprove permissions.

Comment: @AndraZaharia does it crash only at first run on Android 6, after you grant permissions?

Comment: @lidkxx nope, every time I try to save the image :(

Comment: @BrunoFerreira I am approving the permissions already.. do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You are using Unity 5.5 and I think this version is affected by permision problems on Android >=6. You need to download Unity 5.6 or 2017 to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to solve your problem, but most of the cases, there is a permission request problem in above API 23.

Ask request permission in Spalsh screen in above  API 23

```
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    permission = Settings.System.canWrite(this);
                } else {
                    permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                }
                if (!permission) {
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_WRITE_SETTINGS_PERMISSION);

                    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your quick reply! I think the code you are giving me is for Android Studio, whereas my project is in Unity. Could you please guide me to find the specific file you would like me to add this to?

Comment: @Andrazaharia sorry, but I think I don't understand the relationship between Unity editor and Android. Do you actually code your app in Java/Kotlin? I see your manifest file looks like Android file, so what does it mean that "your project is in Unity"?

Comment: @AndraZaharia have you had a look in here? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TroubleShootingAndroid.html there is also a way to get your logs using adb logcat.

Comment: @lidkxx, what I meant was that I only have a Unity project and not an Android one as well. But I managed to export it as gradle project and import into Android Studio. I have added the error to the main post, please can you have a look if it is not too much to ask?

Comment: @AndraZaharia ok, it's much better with the error logs :) I think the problem is in your UnityARPlayerActivity's XML. Probably you're trying to use a View where a ViewGroup (such as FrameLayout/LinearLayout/RelativeLayout...) is required, ex. in a place where you're grouping a few Views. Can you paste your UnityARPlayerActivity XML as well? Or try to google "View cannot be cast to ViewGroup".

Comment: @lidkxx I seem to only have access to the .class file for UnityARPlayerActivity and cannot edit the source code. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: @AndraZaharia sorry, no idea. Have you stumbled upon this? https://github.com/artoolkit/arunity5/issues/150

Comment: @AndraZaharia https://github.com/artoolkit/arunity5/pull/103 there's a fix probably, but they send it by email :>

Comment: @lidkxx You were right. :) I just used the latest gitHub plugin files and it fixed it, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

> please give runtime permission or you can handle this error ....in your build.gradle file do target sdk version 22

Comment: Hello :) Thank you for your reply. I did give runtime permissions and it did not work. I also set the target sdk to 22 in my build.grade files but it still crashes on Android 6. Any other ideas?

Comment: your error is class cast exception right....so you need to casting where this error come ...its not a permission problem